# How to save the user 'Selected Date " into firebase database in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, datepicker

How to save  the user 'Selected Date "  into firebase database in flutter.

I am able to successfully  save the text data into firebase database  where as I am unable to save the User Selected Date into firebase database.

I have used the following imports  and dependancies

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRagePicker;

intl: 0.15.7
date_range_picker: ^1.0.3

mycode in the. dart file is as follows

```
 DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now();
     // DateTime _endDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7));
    
      Future displayDateRangePicker(BuildContext context) async {
        final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialFirstDate: _startDate,
         //   initialLastDate: _endDate,
            firstDate: new DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 50),
            lastDate: new DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 50));
        if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
          setState(() {
            _startDate = picked[0];
          //  _endDate = picked[1];
          });
        }
      }
```

and  in the body part or in Widgets

it is as

```
RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Select  Date"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await displayDateRangePicker(context);
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Warranty Date: ${DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').format(_startDate).toString()}"),
                    //Text("End Date: ${DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').format(_endDate).toString()}"),
                  ],
                ),
```

But it is not saving into the firebase database. P;ease help

Comment: where is the code related to database?

Comment: I have saved earlier into cloud firestore I can provide that code if you want? But this time I want to save into firenase databse only . Please help.

Comment: Have you got the answer how to store data under date in firebase DB? if yes could you provide me with the solution?

Answer (score 3):

to insert database you can use dateTimeObject.millisecondsSinceEpoch to convert it to an int and save that to your db.

if you want you can use DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(msIntFromServer) to convert it back to a DateTime object.

```
int selectedDT=pickedDateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
Firestore.instance.collection('CollectionName').document(docName).setData({
'date_time': selectedDT
 });
```

[To more about this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Comment: Tharaka Dayanjana  Sorry I  am saving into firebase database and not cloud firestore.